# OpenShift3 Latency Issues

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, openshift, wildfly

We have a JEE application with MongoDB running successfully on OpenShift2; we recently migrated to OpenShift3 (Wildfly & MongoDB) and we are experiencing terrible **latency issues**.

A dialog in the app pulls 4.27KB of data:

- **OpenShift3** Lantency: 5790.00ms (5.79s) Duration: 0.146ms
- **OpenShift2** Lantency: 17.66ms Duration: 0.288ms

On both options, we are using the smallest gears/pods.

Any suggestions on improving the latency? We tried from two different Internet providers.

Comment: Which OpenShift 3 environment are you using? There are currently some issues with the routing layer of OpenShift Online Starter environments which are being investigated. Use ``oc rsh`` on the command line, or open a terminal from the web console for a pod and time how long ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080`` takes inside of the container. This will help to identify where is a routing layer issue or a problem with the application.

Comment: I use the Starter environment. I compared the same app on OpenShift2 and 3, and the app is faster on 3, but the latency is more than 5 seconds which make the app unusable. We moved to AWS and running the App Server using the market place. I will try the curl option, but we deleted the app. It takes so long to create an app on OpenShift 3; between timeout and random quotas, it would discourage any developers. I will let you know if I can bring back our app on OpenShift 3. For the record, I used to be quoted on the OpenShift site: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-cloud/openshift/

Comment: I see a lot of: The pod has been stuck in the pending state for more than five minutes. For instance, just deploying a mongodb image provided from OpenShift.

Comment: In the last 40 minutes, I had to re-start the creation of the default mongodb 3 times before it works and now, the same issue with a default Wildfly. This is so far away from what OpenShift used to be.

Comment: Which Starter cluster are you on? I don't know if has a same underlying cause as router issues, but us-east-1 has been seeing some issues with delays in builds and deployments, or failure of them due to the delays. When deployment is done, except for the router issues mentioned, the applications run fine.

Comment: the us-east-1 ; I will try a different cluster and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I did the curl on the east cluster from the Terminal (Web Console) and it takes less than 1 second; I did date && curl $HOSTNAME:8080 && date and the times are identical

Comment: And from the browser, the latency is still more than 3 seconds... 3.5 s in the last test.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The west coast cluster works better...

Answer (score 0):

Graham was correct; the issue was with the east coast cluster. Using the west coast one, the performance to create instances are better without any errors at creation.

To compare the performance using the same test:

- Latency 1410.00 ms (1.41s) Duration: 0.254ms

Still took long of a latency for a Web app, but at least we can test OpenShift3.

Comment: FWIW, they are getting closer to understanding what the issue with us-east-1 is. They have made some changes to alleviate the problem while they dig further.

Comment: OpenShift's answer: "
Will Gordon (OpenShift Online)
Sep 29, 4:40 PM EDT

Hi Greogri,

This latency is due to the high demand and traffic that is on the Starter clusters. We apologize that this latency is so high, however our Starter cluster is strictly for learning about and experimenting with the OpenShift v3 platform. For better performance, support, and resources, I suggest upgrading to OpenShift Online 3 Pro.

If there is anything else we can help with, please let us know.

Thanks!

~ Will
OpenShift Customer Success Team
OpenShift Online by Red Hat, Inc."

Comment: A clarification should be added to that response. The high latency is not what you should expect, even where the starter clusters are under heavy usage. So don't come to the conclusion that this is normal and what you would expect when using OpenShift. Even though the starter clusters are intended for learning and experimentation, the aim is still to provide reasonable performance. In this case the high volume of requests combined with a separate issue was causing the high latency. The separate issue is being looked at.